# Run Scrapy from a script when it gets a request

Tags: python, scrapy, fastapi

I have a **FastAPI** server that is listening to an endpoint, after receiving any post request, it will use **Scrapy** to grab some data depending on that data it's gotten from post request.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


class Request(BaseModel):
    someIDs: List[str]


process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/")
def home(request: Request):
    process.crawl('rt_criteria', ids=request.someIDs)
    process.start()  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
    return {"crawled": True}

# uvicorn main:app --reload
```

This code will run for the first time as I expect, but for the second time, I will get

```
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

error on:

```
process.start()
```

Where should I write this and How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem using [Background tasks](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/) in FastAPI.

(I think it's using multiprocess under the hood.)

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, BackgroundTasks

# *** Not changed codes ***

@app.post("/")
async def home(request: Request, bt: BackgroundTasks):
    process.crawl('rt_criteria', mid=request.movieIDs)
    # Changed line below using Background tasks
    bt.add_task(process.start, stop_after_crawl=False)
    return {"crawled": True}

# uvicorn main:app --reload
```

Comment: Please note that background tasks run in the event loop; hence, if you performed any blocking operations inside a background task, it would block the event loop (and hence, the entire server), unless you defined the background task function with normal `def`, which, in that case, would be run in an external threadpool and then `await`ed. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details.